# Where to find the .bak file after RDS native backup

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, database-backups

So I followed the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html) to perform a native RDS backup using MS-SQL Server. My goal is to be able to download the `.bak` file.

The config seems to be correct, and I was able to execute the backup stored procedure:

[image: stored procedure]

And I created the the option group and have the S3 bucket linked to it.

[image]

But when I went to the S3 bucket, the `.bak` file is not there, even the stored procedure is performed successfully.

Comment: Try using the `rds_task_status` stored procedure to see if any errors occurred during native backup - `exec msdb.dbo.rds_task_status @db_name='aa144bgo6mn8srl'`. Do you see a status of `Completed`?

Comment: @AdilB you are right, none of them are completed. I got two different errors" Aborted the task because of a task failure or an overlap with your preferred backup window for RDS automated backup. [2018-06-12 12:16:22.023] Bucket name cannot be null for S3 ARN. Please make sure bucket name is provided and seperated from object name by forward slash(/) or colon(:)" and " [2018-06-13 08:58:22.160] Aborted the task because of a task failure or a concurrent BACKUP_DB_DIFFERENTIAL request. [2018-06-13 08:58:22.163] Access Denied"

Comment: Great! I'm going to create an answer with this information for future SO searchers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `rds_task_status` stored procedure to see if any errors occurred during native backup - `exec msdb.dbo.rds_task_status @db_name='aa144bgo6mn8srl'`. This will produce a table of sync statuses.

Do you see a `lifecycle` of Completed when you run this query?